# How does a framework run custom client code which is implemented against its exposed interface?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, frameworks

I wonder how frameworks or for example JDK APIs run custom client code which is implemented against the interface it provides.

For example `javax.security` runs the custom code client provided via the implemented methods of the interface. I can't clearly explain myself how the API be able to run implemented class. I think that OK, they expose API via a Java interface, but there must be a runtime or execution mechanism to run that custom code.

```java
import javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule;

public class CustomerLoginModule implements LoginModule {
   ...
}

package javax.security.auth.spi;

import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.AuthPermission;
import javax.security.auth.callback.*;
import javax.security.auth.login.*;
import java.util.Map;

public interface LoginModule {

    void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
                    Map<String,?> sharedState,
                    Map<String,?> options);

    boolean login() throws LoginException;

    boolean commit() throws LoginException;

    boolean abort() throws LoginException;

    boolean logout() throws LoginException;
}
```

How does Java Security API runs client code which is against this interface internally? How does it works under the hood?

Or for example this, again just in the context of interface, I can't explain myself clearly how does this API run custom client code.

```
package java.util;
public interface EventListener {

}

package com.xxx;
import java.util.EventListener;
public interface IPreferenceObserver extends EventListener {
    void onPreferenceChange();
}
```

Comment: Let's say somewhere in the JDK, there is a bit of code that calls a method of an implementation of `EventListener` when a certain event happens. Now, if you have specified your particular implementation to be that event listener, your code will be called. It all works thanks to [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: Thank you but I know something about polymorphism, dynamic dispatch or interface keyword. What I can't figure out is this type of Interface usage seems some kind of different to me. When it comes to writing your own application, you use Interface and benefit from its polymorphism features, but in the case of a framework it builds a mechanism via interface and use it to run custom client code. For example in my ```javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule``` example, how does it run my custom code? What if there isn't any implementation of that interface, how does it check that?

Comment: [This page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/spi/LoginModule.html) explains clearly how `LoginContext` determines which implementation to use to perform the authentication.